# The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, iis

I know that this is a common problem facing over, but am getting this this problem with a different scenario.
am going to explain scenario here

I created a two different projects in a solution. The image containing folder that i want to use for save, i-e upload is outside of these above projects but under same solution.
Actually i created virtual directly (My File Server) on IIS server of this folder

here is my code.

```
private void SaveData()
        {


            string filename = Path.GetFileName(ImageUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
            string servpath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempFolder"]);
            ImageUpload.SaveAs(servpath + filename);
            string remoteServerPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductImagesPath"] + filename;
            try
            {

                WebClient client = new WebClient();

                client.UploadFile(remoteServerPath, servpath + filename);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;

            }
            objProductsCustom.ProductName = txtProductName.Text;
            objProductsCustom.ProductDiscription = txtAddDiscription.Text;
            objProductsCustom.ProductPrice = txtPrice.Text;
            objProductsCustom.Quantity = txtQuantity.Text;
            objProductsCustom.ImagePath = "servpath" + filename;
            int productID = objProductsManager.CreatProduct(objProductsCustom);

        }
```

Where on try-catch, I found "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Allowed." error. I am stuck.

**EDIT**
This is the remoteserverpath :

```
http://localhost/ProductImages/untitled.bmp
```

And this is the file which i am uploading to remoteserverpath:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\saltaf\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects  \OnlineShoppingSystem\OnlineShoppingSiteAdminPanel\Temp\Images\untitled.bmp
```

And this is my call:

```
 webclient.UploadFile(http://localhost/ProductImages/untitled.bmp,C:\Documents and  Settings\saltaf\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\OnlineShoppingSystem\OnlineShoppingSiteAdminPanel\Temp\Images\untitled.bmp)
```

Comment: Why do you have this in Quotes objProductsCustom.ImagePath = "servpath"

Comment: This seems to be typo. but the issue is not that. lets stick with the issue.

Comment: Saquib is this a typo..?

Comment: go to IIS and then open directory browsing and enable it, this should work

Comment: When you call `client.UploadFile`, what is the value of `remoteServerPath`?  And what application/site/other sits at that Url?  I suspect you're trying to upload to a HTTP Url that doesn't support `POST` but, since it's not clear what your server is, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I have just Edited my Question, please review it

Comment: Do you mean 405 Method _Not_ Allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you  tried checking the permissions for the folder which you are saving the file into? It's supposed to include the 'IIS_IUSRS' profile there (which should also have the WRITE permission to the target folder).

Hope this helps.